# Javaagent gives ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, manifest.mf, javaagents

I am trying to use a javaagent called LoggerAgent to get details of log some Java applications. But I am getting a ClassNotDefinedException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.LoggerAgent
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:304)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:401)
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed
Aborted
```

Interestingly, if I run the javaagent on the same LoggerAgent class (I have intentionally defined a main function in it to test this), then the program works normally. In case it is necessary, I am pasting the manifest file of the javaagent (named as agent.jar) here:

```
Premain-Class: com.LoggerAgent
Class-Path: lib/javassist.jar
Agent-Class: com.LoggerAgent
Boot-Class-Path: agent.jar
```

Any ideas about what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the classpath for the main class (the one you wrote intentionally) and the classpath for the class in which you are getting the exception.

The Class-Path in the manifest is relative to the executable JAR the way you've written it.

Comment: Can someone provide some insight on why this is the correct answer and WHAT was actually wrong?

Answer (score -1):

maybe you should check mvn puligin
`mvn clean package` or mvn jar plug